# Rails - Sendgrid: Emails using html.erb files instead of plain html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, embedded-ruby

I am using Sendgrid to send emails with my backend on Rails 5. I manage to send plain html files, but I can't send html.erb files. In general it works, but the embedded ruby doesn't take effect.

html.erb file:

```
<h1>Count <%= 2+2 %></h1>
```

Actual Output

```
Count <%= 2+2 %>
```

Desired Output

```
Count 4
```

The emails do deliver to my inbox.

I tried following this tutorial https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html but that doesn't deliver emails at all. What does work is using the gem with the API key https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby

Comment: its not sendgrid issue, make sure file type is `.html.erb` and layout too.

Comment: @7urkm3n it is type html.erb